# angular value is not reflecting from the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to assign value to $scope variable from a controller function. I can see the value is assigned from console but it is not reflecting in html page.

my html

```
<div id="NodeDetails" class="NodeDetails">{{NodeDetails}}</div>
```

my controller function

```
$scope.ShowDetails = function() {
    $scope.NodeDetails = "in am called in function";
    console.log($scope.NodeDetails)     
};
```

i can see the data in console but same is not displayed in html.

it works when i put,

```
$scope.NodeDetails = "in am called in individual";
```

is there any specific way to set variable in function. I have tried by return value also but that also didn't work.

```
$scope.NodeDetails = function() {
return "in am called in function";  
};
```

please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It should work either way, here's an example of different type of setters

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.val = "default value";
  
  $scope.change = function(){
    $scope.val = $scope.text;
    $scope.text ="";
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{val}}
<input type="text" ng-model="text" placeholder="Add something"/>
<button ng-click="change()">Change</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It works in this way but in my case , can not get value from input. is it possible to assign value to val directly ? like ,  $scope.val = "text";

Comment: @sand yes, in the example I set the $scope.val = "default value";

Comment: @sand please show the complete view and controller that you are using

Comment: i didn't know how to put full code here so i have asked another question and put code in there. please refer the link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355350/angular-set-scope-value-in-controller-function-is-not-working"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating NodeDetails as a string, change it to an object and try changing it https://jsfiddle.net/paka2/d0mf0g9j/1/

```
<div id="NodeDetails" class="NodeDetails">{{nodeObject.NodeDetails}}</div>   
$scope.nodeObject = {
NodeDetails: ""
}
```

This solves the problem of any child scope issue